# I can't issue a role when the user clicks on reaction

Tags: c#, discord.net

As you can see if you remove the code where it was issued, that when the user clicks on reaction, it is scored and will come out as a response in the form of a user name. Because I wrote this method in the Program and added the legacy ModuleBase it is finite, I will have to return null, I always pixel this problem just dobavlyu in the parameters of the desired class, but now I can't add more than 3 classes because the field ReactionAdded takes 3 parameters, for reaction, tell me how inside the method to take classes SocketGuild,SocketGuildUser and Yes role variable returns Null because ModuleBase

```
 [Command("react")]
        public async Task HandleReaction()
        {
            RestUserMessage message = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("react");
            Program.MessageId = message.Id;
        }

internal static ulong MessageId { get; set; }
  public  ITextChannel textChannel;

    public SocketGuildUser user;    

private async Task OnReactionAdd(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> cache, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
        {
          
            if (reaction.MessageId == Program.MessageId)
            {
                  if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
            {
                

                ulong roleid = 747992707351183541;
                var role = textChannel.Guild.GetRole(roleid); //System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

                await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
                await channel.SendMessageAsync(reaction.User.Value.Username);
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please reword your question. I'm not sure if you used a translator or something but your question isn't very clear and somewhat hard to follow. Based on the code, I can say that you **cannot** use the reaction added event handler inside of a command module, it should be in a separate service class. You can get the guild from the ISocketMessageChannel by casting it to a text channel. And you can get the user from the SocketReaction.

Comment: @Anu6is I have a variable role ModuleBase<T> returns null, to fix this error, I need to add SocketGuild arg to the method parameters, and write this way var role = arg.GetRole(roleId) but I can't add SocketGuild to the method parameters since I assign the OnReactionAdd method to the ReactionAdded field, so I write _client. ReactionAdded += OnReactionAdd; the ReactionAdded field takes 3 parameters that you can see in the OnReactionAdd method, I hope this time I explained clearly

Comment: `I need to add SocketGuild arg to the method parameters` you can't add your own parameters to an event handler signature. Which is why I stated you can get the Guild by casting the `ISocketMessageChannel` to a `ITextChannel` and accessing it's `Guild` property.... also, `I have a variable role ModuleBase<T> returns null` this still does not make sense to me becuase you can't utilize event handlers in classes that inherit from module base.

Comment: @Anu6is I added the public itextchannel textChannel field; and wrote my code like this and still in the role null variable If I replace ISocketMessageChannel with ITextChannel, _client.ReactionAdded += OnReactionAdd will not work for me;
`ulong roleid = 747992707351183541;

                    var txt = textChannel;

                    var role = txt.Guild.GetRole(roleid);

                    await ((SocketGuildUser)Context.User).AddRoleAsync(role);`

Comment: You still appear to be doing this within a class that inherits module base. That is simply not going to work. Context is not valid outside of actual commands. That said, you don't show how to you cast the ISocketMessageChannel to ITextChannel. I never said to replace on with the other.

Comment: @Anu6is That is, the method I should write OnReactionAdd in another class 1 question should it be static or not, and 2 question should this class not inherit from ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>? _client.ReactionAdded += OnReactionAdd; this is written in my program class

Comment: No, the class that has the event handler should not inherit from module base. It doesn't matter if it's static or not. I don't see the need for it to be but that may be dependant on other things in your code. It would be easier if you edited the question with your code instead of using the comments btw

Comment: @Anu6is All right now

Comment: @Anu6is I edited I know that  `public ITextChannel textChannel; public SocketGuildUser user;` = null but I don't know how to make them not equal null sorry for taking so long

Comment: You declare a variable `textChannel` but you never assign it a value (of course it's null). I've stated three times that you should **cast** the `ISocketMessageChannel` (channel)  to an `ITextChannel` if you don't understand what casting is or how to cast you should have stated so or done some research. Your `user` variable is also declared with no value set...again this will result in a null ref error.

Comment: @Anu6is I did it in the string role now there is no exception, but now the exception is here wait `user.AddRoleAsync(role);` what should I do now to get ContexUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
private async Task OnReactionAdd(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> cache, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
{  
    if (reaction.MessageId == Program.MessageId)
    {
        if (reaction.Emote.Name == "")
        {
            ulong roleid = 747992707351183541;
            //here can cast the ISocketMessageChannel to an ITextChannel
            if (channel is SocketTextChannel textChannel) 
            {
                var role = textChannel.Guild.GetRole(roleid); 
                var user = textChannel.Guild.GetUser(reaction.UserId);
                
                await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
                await textChannel.SendMessageAsync(user.Username);
            }   
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: "IGuild" does not contain a "GetUser" definition, and an available "GetUser" extension method that takes the "IGuild" type as the first argument could not be found (the using Directive or Assembly reference may have been omitted)

Comment: change ITextChannel to SocketTextChannel

Comment: thank you for the new experience, and thank you for your time and help!